# why does while loop giving a different result?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
int nub=0;
while(nub<=300){        
std::cout<<"total ="<<nub<<"\n";    
nub++;
}
```

why the output of this loop is starting from 5 rather than 0.well the output of this loop should be from 0 to 300 but the number is starting from 5 rather than 0. whats wrong with that loop even the value of nub is zero.

Comment: it does start at `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/QQEMBQ Is it possible that your terminals line buffer is full and you cannot see the first lines? Try to increase it (or make the loop only go till `295`)

Comment: yes, it is starting from 0, no errors in it.